# Stanford Parser training error

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am learning to use the stanford parser and train it with a gold standard annotated MiPACQ corpus and as a preliminary step, I was trying to train it as a PCFG parser exactly as mentioned in the FAQ #26 
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#p

However, I get an error saying that it could not find or load the main class for the Lexicalized Parser. I have read the java source code file and I could find the main class. Pardon me if the question is too trivial but I do not understand where my error lies. I used  proper(PTB format) sample training and test files.

I am not sure if I should be following specific path settings to make it work and I am fairly new and almost clueless on using java in command line. Hoping somebody could help.

Comment: Hi @RamyaV. This is not related to your question but how did you download the MiPACQ corpus? I have been looking everywhere and I cannot find a way to access it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found the answer myself. To those who are wondering how to train the stanford parser in command line on windows, Dr.Manning has himself provided an answer along with the classpath specifications. Here is the resource link. 
https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2010-May/000407.html